# Can you suggest a reversible process whereby heat can be added to a system? Would adding heat by means of a gas stove be a reversible process?

Tags: thermodynamics, reversibility

Can you suggest a reversible process whereby heat can be added to a system? 
Would adding heat by means of a gas stove be a reversible process?
I am trying to understand thermodynamics and the whole thing is confusing

Comment: you might see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible_process_(thermodynamics) or specifically https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible_process_(thermodynamics)#Boundaries_and_states

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the only requirement for a process to be reversible is it should be done very slowly (in infinitely many steps) such that the system is always in equilibrium with surroundings. Any kind of process, say isobaric or isochoric or isothermal can be conducted in a reversible manner.

Actually in isochoric process, you have to supply the heat in infinitesimal increments such that the system is always in equilibrium with the surroundings. (*The temperature of surroundings should be $dT$ greater than that of the system*).

In isobaric process, the process has to be carried out very slowly such that the difference of pressures of the system and the surroundings is always $dP$. That means the work is done in increments of $\delta W$.

In an isothermal process, heat has to be added or removed such that after the system and surroundings have changed their states, the temperature of the system is $T_\text{initial}$. Both the work done (*positive or negative*) and the addition or removal of heat has to be conducted in very small steps so as not to disturb the system and surroundings from equilibrium.

> Would adding heat by means of a gas stove be a reversible process?

I don't think that's possible because the system will receive uneven heating and hence won't suffer smooth changes. Moreover, reversibility is an idealized model which helps  make processes more efficient. No process can be truly $100\%$ reversible.

Comment: @Gag Gago If you must, you could probably draw some fully reversible processes out of the woodwork thru addition of a "cosmology" tag, but, as they wouldn't be verifiable through experiment or observation, the word "truly" in this answer seems to me to leave it completely valid in a purely scientific context.

Comment: Be careful about the distinction between reversible and quasistatic. Quasistatic means slow enough that a given system moves through a sequence of states, each of which is an internal equilibrium state, but this does not necessarily imply reversible. e.g. slowing squeezing toothpaste out of a tube is quasistatic but thermodynamically irreversible. There's a lot of irreversibility involved with heat transfer on a typical gas stove, especially because the flame is hotter than the thing it is heating.

Comment: @Andrew Steane while I understand the point you are making, that a quasi static process is not necessarily reversible because of friction, generally that is associated with irreversible work and not irreversible heat transfer. The OP is asking about irreversible heat transfer. If the heat transfer is quasistatic it doesn’t generate entropy because heat transfer over a finite temperature difference does not in itself involve friction.

Answer (score 1):

> Can you suggest a reversible process whereby heat can be added to a
>   system?

Only in theory. Examples are the reversible isothermal processes of a Carnot Cycle.  Because a reversible process would take an infinite amount of time for the reversible process to finish, a perfect reversible process is not possible. To explain:

In order for heat transfer to be reversible, the difference in temperature between the heat source and the system has to approach zero. This means the transfer would have to occur infinitely slowly (quasi-statically). Since any real heat transfer process that takes a finite amount of time requires a finite temperature difference, all real heat transfer processes are irreversible. The perfect reversible process is an idealization that can never be attained in reality. It is useful for determining things like the maximum possible theoretical efficiency for producing work.

> Would adding heat by means of a gas stove be a reversible process?

No, as it is unlikely you could control the transfer to be carried out with an infinitely small temperature difference between the gas flame and the object being heated. There will always be a finite temperature between difference, and heat transfer across a finite temperature difference is irreversible.

The following may help you to see how heat transfer is irreversible. You know that heat transfers naturally (spontaneously) from a higher temperature object to a lower temperature object. Now consider the reverse process. Would you expect that same heat that transferred from the hot object to the cold object to naturally go in the reverse direction from the cold object to the hot object? In order to do that, external work is required. For example, the only reason why an air conditioner can transfer heat from a low temperature environment (indoors) to a higher temperature environment (outdoors) is that it has a compressor that does work to accomplish the transfer.

Hope this helps.